# meteor create project failing

Tags: github, meteor

os: window 10

when I create meteor project, it shows following error. So I can not learn Meteor.

```
C:\test>meteor create asd
C:\Users\msm08\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

Error: Error: Could not install npm dependencies for test-packages: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\Users\msm08\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd install --production=false
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\msm08\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-01T17_24_26_459Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\msm08\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-01T17_24_26_459Z-debug.log

    at Object.error (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:430:11)
    at C:\tools\cli\default-npm-deps.js:36:20
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:334:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:333:36
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at Object.install (C:\tools\cli\default-npm-deps.js:27:27)
    at Command.func (C:\tools\cli\commands.js:801:36)
    at C:\tools\cli\main.js:1523:15
```

Comment: Do you have git installed and in your path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to install the GIT for windows version from this [LINK](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.16.3.windows.1/Git-2.16.3-64-bit.exe)

It will automatically set the environment variable for GIT on your windows 10 machine. You do not have to do anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Check the $path if it contains a Git:

go to this pc -> advanced System Setting -> Environmental Variables

check the Path if it contains GIT.

you can also check it via command prompt and type "Path"